# Install intel centrino wireless controller firmeware in linux-libre

Tags: wireless, drivers, intel-wireless, firmware

I have the following wireless network controller:

> 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2200 [8086:0891] (rev c4)
>
> > Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2200 BGN [8086:4222]
> >
> > Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

It works well on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. But if I want to use a linux-libre as kernel, it fails due to lack of related firmware on linux-libre.

How can I install the firmware?

Comment: If you're willing to install proprietary firmware on linux-libre, doesn't it defeat the purpose? Why don't you just use Ubuntu with the standard kernel?

Comment: Yes it does, but using a proprietary bios on your computer does defeat the purpose too… That is not a sole point to reach, It's a road to freedom and you should be able to go as further as you can. In my case there is no other other solution available, and believe me, I am truly upset for this.

Comment: Close voters: Why is this not about Ubuntu?

Comment: This is relevant also for several ThinkPad laptops, e.g. X230 and T430. http://blog.burntsushi.net/lenovo-thinkpad-t430-archlinux/

Answer (score 2):

The firmware for the 2200 is located in the Ubuntu package `linux-firmware` - the driver is provided by intel, but not the source code.  You can find specific firmware downloads at [intel](http://www.intel.com/support/wireless/wlan/sb/CS-034398.htm).

Comment: It is found in _linux-firmware_; not _linux-firmware-nonfree_.

Comment: @chili555  You are correct - I will amend the answer.  There's something in the `-nonfree` that my Dell needs to run properly, and I have forgotten what it is.

Comment: Package linux-firmware is instralled and so is the iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode firwmware file, but when I log into Ubuntu with linux-libre kernel, wireless doesn't function at all. I checked and found even iwlwifi kernel module is loaded too.